# How to create a fixed size SwiftUI Button when label content changes?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I've got a SwiftUI Button, and it's label changes when it's clicked.
The code looks like this:

```
struct MyButton: View {
    var label: String
    @State var loading = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: { loading.toggle() }) {
            if (loading) {
                Text("...")
            } else {
                Text(label)
            }
        }
        .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
    }
}


struct MyButton_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MyButton(label: "This is a button")
    }
}
```

When it's rendered, the button changes size when it's clicked and it's label content changes, as you can see here:

[image: button]

How can I get the button to remain the same size no matter what it's label content is?
I'm hoping to find a solution that doesn't require hard coding a frame size or something like that, because I'm trying to create a generic, reusable button that can have any label.

By way of example of what I'm looking for, in Compose, I can use a custom layout for this. I can measure both the `Text` view for the "loading" state and the `Text` view for the "non-loading" state, and then set the parent/button size to the larger of the two, and then only place the `Text` that should be visible, resulting in a button that's big enough to show either label, and can switch between the two. Is there anything like that in SwiftUI?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the button to adopt its natural size for the full label then you can use a hidden version of the label to establish the footprint and then show the relevant label as an overlay. This avoids the need to set a frame with any kind of minimum or fixed width.

```swift
Button(action: { loading.toggle() }) {
    Text(label)
        .hidden()
        .overlay(Text(loading ? "..." : label))
}
.buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
```

[image: Loading]

If you don't know which of the two labels is the longest then you can use a `ZStack` to establish the footprint instead:

```swift
ZStack {
    Text(label)
    Text("...")
}
.hidden()
.overlay( /* as before */ )
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a fixed-size SwiftUI Button with a changing label, use a VStack with conditional Text views and set a fixed size with the frame modifier. Adjust *opacity* based on the loading state.

```
struct MyButton: View {
    var label: String
    @State var loading = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: { loading.toggle() }) {
            VStack {
                Text(label)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .opacity(loading ? 0 : 1) 
                Text("...")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .opacity(loading ? 1 : 0) 
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 50) // Set your desired fixed size
        }
        .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `overlay`

```
struct AnimatedButton: View {
    var label: String
    @State var loading = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: { loading.toggle() }) {
            Text(label)
                .overlay {
                    if loading {                        
                        ZStack {
                            Color.accentColor // accent color is the background color for `.borderedProminent`
                            Text("...")
                        }
                    }
                }
        }.buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
    }
}
```

And if you want to add a little animation you can use `TimelineView`.

```
struct AnimatedButton: View {
    var label: String
    @State var loading = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: { loading.toggle() }) {
            Text(label)
                .overlay {
                    if loading {
                        ZStack {
                            Color.accentColor //Cover the label
                            TimelineView(.periodic(from: .now, by: 1)) { context in //Use context for animation
                                let curr = Int(context.date.timeIntervalSince1970) % 3
                                let str = (0...curr).map { _ in
                                    "."
                                }.joined()
                                Text(str)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        }.buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
    }
}
```

If you don't want to hardcode the color and you can always "hide" the label with opacity.

```
struct AnimatedButton: View {
    var label: String
    @State var loading = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: { loading.toggle() }) {
            Text(label)
                .opacity(loading ? 0 : 1) //Hide the label
                .overlay {
                    if loading {
                        TimelineView(.periodic(from: .now, by: 1)) { context in
                            let curr = Int(context.date.timeIntervalSince1970) % 3
                            let str = (0...curr).map { _ in
                                "."
                            }.joined()
                            Text(str)
                        }
                    }
                }
        }.buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
    }
}
```